# android LinearLayout display issue

Tags: android, xml, android-linearlayout

[Problem Solved] I don't know why the height: wrap_content doesn't work as I expected, I just changed it to match parent. Anyway, problem solved. Don't want to spend more time on this weird thing anymore.

I'm using LinearLayout to construct the CardView. However, I get this weird situation. Jinesh Francis's code works perfectly, but when I copy and paste the configuration into my code, the problem stays the same.

[image: Normal Title]

[image: Long Long Title]

Why can't the Long Title be completely displayed?

The layout is as below:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/movieCardView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@color/bacgroundCardView">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/movieImage"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/selfie" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="0dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/movieTitle"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="8"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:text="Long long long long long long long long  Title"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/movieRating"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.7"
                    android:textSize="12dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:text="7.0" />

                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/checkBox"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:scaleX="0.70"
                    android:scaleY="0.70" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/movieDescription"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="10dp"
                android:text="So many many many many many many many many many many many many description" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Thanks for any suggestion

Comment: It's not enough to only write the XML tags. Edit your post and include the attributes as well.

Comment: post your complete layout file

Comment: you are using LinearLayout within relativeLayout, and setting weight of title.. thats why it is giving this output

Comment: I have switched to LinearLayout, but the problem stays the same...

Comment: I don't know why the height: wrap_content doesn't work as I expected, I just changed it to match parent. Anyway, problem solved. Don't want to spend more time on this weird thing anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with linear layouts with weights like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/demo2"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="0dp">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="Long Long Long Long Long Tittle"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.25"
                android:text="7.0"/>
            <CheckBox
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight=".25"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:text="so many many many many many many many many many many many many many  many many many description"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I got this output

[image: Output]

Comment: Thanks for your help Jinesh. It's funny that your code runs perfectly, but when I copy and paste the configuration line by line from your code to mine, the problem stays the same, I feel myself fooled by Android Studio,,

Answer (score 2):

set RelativeLayout Property for adjust your layout

```
Relative Layout Property are below
alignparentLeft,alignLeft
alignparentRight,alignRight
alignparentBottom,alignBottom
alignparentTop,alignTop
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Divyesh, seems that those properties are not the key.